# how do i override a value in a file with environment variable in centos

Tags: apache, centos

Is there any way we can override a value in a httpd configuration using system environment variables.

I have set env variable with export command and called that variable in to override a access.log to someone.log in httpd.conf file after restart of httpd it has created a log filename $someone.log.

I was logged in as a root user and set env, setting up for apache user will it help.

Comment: What kind of file? How do you "print it"? How is this related to Apache?

Comment: Httpd.conf file.. And log name chage

Answer (score 0):

In Apache configuration files, the correct syntax is `${VAR}`. If you used `$VAR`, it will not consider this a variable but a normal string.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/configuring.html